# How to add data of two different serializers to be passed as reference in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models A and B which are not related to each other.
I want to serialize those two models and send them as one JSON object, supposedly as below:

```
{
    'A': {},
    'B': {}
}
```

I have separate serializers for both A and B

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414928/combining-two-different-serializers-into-one-view-returning-named-json-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look. I am overriding get method. Here a_obj, b_obj are the python object maybe is obtained from database.

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
class TwoSerializedModelAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a_obj = A.objects.get(id=1)
        b_obj = B.objects.get(id=1)
        data = {'A': ASerializer(a_obj).data, 'B': BSerializer(b_obj).data}
        return Response(data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DjangoMultiModelApi [libraray](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), in this library you can combine multiple model data with pagination.

and 
second solution is :

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    a_serialzer_data = serializer_classA(query_setA, many=True)
    b_serialzer_data = serializer_classB(query_setB, many=True)
    return Response({
        "A": a_serialzer_data.data,
        "B": b_serialzer_data.data
    })
```

Comment: how to add the data of these serializers if I want the return Response to be something like ```return Response({a_serialzer_data.data, b_serialzer_data.data})```, don't want the keys A & B in my JSON packet.

Comment: `return Response({**a_serialzer_data.data, **b_serialzer_data.data})`  

b_serialzer_data.data is a dict so needed to make single dict from two dict and return @Voldemort

Answer (score 1):

From [Django Rest Framework documentation on Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects):

> The Serializer class is itself a type of Field, and can be used to represent relationships where one object type is nested inside another.

So you can just create serializer class with fields "A" and "B" as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ABSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    A = ASerializer()
    B = BSerializer()
```

and use it like this:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class ABView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ABSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return {'a': self.get_object_a(), 'b': self.get_object_b()}
```