# DRF : modify model structure without modifying serialization output

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my current model I have JSON field called "data", previously "foo" and "bar" fields was inside the JSON field. For performance reasons I had to externalize foo and bar to dedicated fields with a django migration.

but i would like to keep the same endpoint format when reaching the API. Which means put "foo" and "bar" in the **class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer)**

How is it possible to share the data from FooModelSerializer() to the DataSerializer() ?

endpoint output format:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1
            "data": {
                "json_field_A": "charValue",
                "json_field_B": 123,
                "json_field_C": "charValue",
                "foo": 12,
                "bar": "barValue"
            },
            "other": 12345
        },
        {
            "id": 2
            "data": {
                "json_field_A": "charValue",
                "json_field_B": 123,
                "json_field_C": "charValue",
                "foo": 12,
                "bar": "barValue"
            },
            "other": 12345
        }
]
```

model :

```py
class FooModel(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=some_default
    )
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.CharField()
    other = models.IntegerField()
```

serializer :

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    json_field_A = fields.CharField()
    json_field_B = fields.IntegerField()
    json_field_C = fields.CharField()

class FooModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = DataSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.FooModel
        fields = ['id', 'data', 'other', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListAPIView to kinda combine these two serializers and write one view that handles them both.

```
class CombinedListView(ListAPIView):
   serializer_class_data = DataSerializer
   serializer_class_foo = FooModelSerializer

   def get_data(self):
      return DataModel.objects.all()
   
   def get_foo(self):
      return FooModel.objects.all()

   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      data = self.serializer_class_data(self.get_data(), many=True)
      foo = self.serializer_class_foo(self.get_foo(), many=True)
      return Response({"data": data, "foo": foo})
```

I suggest you use some class methods and call them inside the main method that returns the response.

Here is a link to a similar situation: [Combining Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414928/combining-two-different-serializers-into-one-view-returning-named-json-arrays)

Comment: Actually there is only one model, data is a JSONfield() in the FooModel. So i'm not sure that the solution you propose could fit with my constraints. 
I thought about to "hack" the to_representation() method in the DataSerializer and trying to access the data from the parent serializer through self.parent.instance to get the field value. But it's a list of <models.FooModel>. So impossible to know which element in this list fit with the current representation..